# Next closest element jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

The HTML:

```
<a class="button">Button</a>
<input type="submit" />

<a class="button">Button</a>
<div>
  <!-- The input there can be into an another `div`, etc .. -->
  <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

When I click on a link with the class `button` how I can target the **next closest** `input[type=submit]` ?

Comment: Will be much simpler if you wrap groups of repeating components so that traversals are more localized based on searches inside wrapping container

Comment: So what ? jQuery can't do what I REALLY want ?

Comment: Sure it can... but requires more complex search than if you organize the dom better

Comment: I'm writing a jQuery plugin for something and i can't have the real control about the HTML markup.

Comment: OK.. well that piece of information would have been helpful also. Does that mean you may have no idea where the buttons are? Can they be indexed (always 1:1 relationship)?

Comment: That's what i was writing in my plugin (the 1:1 relationship), it works, but i think it would be interesting to have a "regular" solution about my question ;)

Comment: There is no regular solution without seeing all the possible variations or organizing the html structure better. I can give you code that works for html shown quite easily.... but it would assume that an input is either the next element or only one exists inside next element

Comment: I found that plugin on github https://github.com/jjenzz/jQuery.nearest, maybe it will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

A method just occurred to me that is actually fairly simple but would require knowing the top level parent that contains all of the `<a>` and `<input>` involved or adding a class to the `input`'s

You create a collection of just the `<a>` and `type=submit` involved.

When an `<a>` is clicked, you use it's index in the previous collection to filter out all the input's that come after it's index and take the first one

```
var $buttons = $('#mainContainer').find('a.button, input[type=submit]');
$('#mainContainer a.button').click(function(){
    var index = $buttons.index(this);
    var $input = $buttons.filter('input:gt(' + index +')').first(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to traverse the DOM to find the element whose type is submit. In the following code - I'm checking in the following way

1. Is the current element's type submit. If yes - then end the loop and return current element.
2. Look for any child of the current element.
3. Look for next siblings, and their children
4. Look for parents and their siblings and their children

We will be calling our function recursively for each element till we find what we are looking for

```
function findButton(ctrl, skipChildren) {
    var controlToReturn = null;
    if ($(ctrl).prop('type') === 'submit') {
        controlToReturn = $(ctrl);
    } else {
        //We need to skip children in case the call is coming from the child (else we will be stuck in infinite loop)
        if(!skipChildren){
            $(ctrl).children().each(function () {
                controlToReturn = findButton($(this));
                if (controlToReturn != null) {
                    return false; //break
                }
            });
        }

        if (controlToReturn === null || controlToReturn === undefined) {
            //Loop through the next siblings
            $(ctrl).nextAll().each(function () {
                controlToReturn = findButton($(this));
                if (controlToReturn != null) {
                    return false; //break
                }
            });
        }

        if (controlToReturn === null || controlToReturn === undefined) {
            //Go to parent and find the element in parents siblings. Note we are passing true as second parameter of this function.
            $(ctrl).parents().each(function(){
                controlToReturn = findButton($(this), true);
                if (controlToReturn != null) {
                    return false; //break
                }
            });
        }
    }

    return controlToReturn;
}
```

See a working example at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/3b1d0sk5/) link.